# Match string from DataFrame column of strings to other DataFrame columns of strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I want to iterate through a column, 'c', and extract strings which match strings present in columns a or b.

The code I have tried so far:

```
def find_nodes(a, b, c):
list1 =  []
for tweet in c:
    if tweet in (a or b):
        list1.append(tweet)
return list1

data = [{'a':['lyd'], 'b':['joe hk'], 'c':['ben jh','julios fd','jim']},
    {'a':['ben jh'], 'b':['dogge fgr'], 'c':['kull', 'doggj fgr']},
     {'a':['mart'], 'b':['jack'], 'c':['kim','bruce','lyd']}]

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df3['a'] = df3['a'].astype(str)
df3['b'] = df3['b'].astype(str)
df3['c'] = df3['c'].astype(str)

df3['d'] = df3[['a','b', 'c']].apply(lambda df3: find_nodes(df3['a'],df3['b'], df3['c']), axis=1)
```

But it produces this: (see actual output), and I would like this (see desired output)
thanks [actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKItx.png) [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD6He.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dfc = df.c.reset_index().explode('c')
dfc['d'] = dfc.c.isin(df.a.explode('a')) | dfc.c.isin(df.b.explode('b'))
dfc = dfc[dfc.d].set_index('index')
dfc = dfc.groupby(dfc.index).agg(list)
df['d'] = dfc.c
```

Output:

```
          a            b                         c            d
0     [lyd]     [joe hk]  [ben jh, julios fd, jim]     [ben jh]
1  [ben jh]  [doggj fgr]         [kull, doggj fgr]  [doggj fgr]
2    [mart]       [jack]         [kim, bruce, lyd]        [lyd]
```

Explanation:

- Use `df.c.reset_index()` to create a dataframe with 2 columns: `index` and `c`
- Use `explode('c')` to populate `dfc` with one row for each item in the lists in column `c` with the associated value of the `index` column
- Use `isin()`, `explode('a')` and `explode('b')`together with the `or` operator `|` to populate column `d` of dfc with a boolean for each value in column `c` of `dfc` indicating whether that value is in one of the lists in columns `a` and `b` of the original dataframe
- Use `dfc[dfc.d]` to mask `dfc` and retain only the `True` values in column `d`
- Use `set_index()` to populate the index of `dfc` with the corresponding index values from the original dataframe
- Use `groupby()` and `agg(list)` to group items with like index value into  one list per unique index value; these are the sub-lists of matching strings from column c present in columns a or b in the original dataframe
- Use `df['d'] = dfc.c` to employ reindexing to populate a new column `d` in `df` containing the sub-lists of matching strings.

Comment: Do you need any additional help with your question?

Comment: If you're satisfied with this answer, please consider marking it "accepted".